# Open app when home button preseed in android

Tags: android

When I press home button in android phone

at ant time open my application

How I Do it, Please ???

And How I Exit from app (not go to the last Activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding the Home Button is not a recommended thing to do. The Home Button serves as a panic/safe button for the user whenever something goes out of hand. Overriding the Home Button will present issues if you make it open another application.

You can override it to open another application, however, the Android OS will ask the user to choose between the default home button application (the one that brings you back to the home page of the device) or your application. At this moment, the user can set a default application to go to. If I'm not mistaken, it will take root access to completely override the home button in such a way that the above mentioned process of choosing a default application.